# Как получить инфу по каналам Telegram для сайта?

Tags: telegram

Необходимо регулярно получать для сайта кол-во подписчиков и аватары по указанным логинам каналов.
Возможно ли это реализовать?
На официальном сайте вижу только API для ботов и API для разработки приложений на базе *Telegram*.

Comment: Создал бота и получаю инфу через него.

Answer (score 0):

Яндекс метрику подцепить

[Собираем аналитику при помощи Botan](https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter6.html) вот тут посмотри пример;)